# What is the '#" symbol in Pascal?

Tags: delphi, pascal

For example:

```
x := #123;
```

I tried to search around Google but I simply have no idea what this means.

Comment: # is known as "Number sign", "hash symbol" or  in the US "pound sign"

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for what it is called.

Comment: Ever heard of charmap.exe? # is U+0023: "NUMBER SIGN".

Comment: #123 = '{', by the way. (U+007B: "LEFT CURLY BRACKET")

Comment: You might want to look at the Delphi Language Guide:
Top Level: 
http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/languageguidepart_xml.html
Character literals:
http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/fundamentalsyntacticelementsov_xml.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIRC it means a character value of the number (eg. #32 -> space).

Comment: #123 is the same thing as Chr(123), except it's a literal character constant instead of a builtin system function (Chr).

Comment: FWIW, these days, Chr(32) does nothing. In reality it is not even a function, it is completely equivalent to #32 and Char(32).

Answer (score 7):

`#123` is a character (`Char` type) of the ordinal value `123`.

Answer (score 4):

It's character code. #97 is equivalent to 'a' etc etc

A chart can be see [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/ASCII).

Comment: What does == mean? In Delphi, you use := for assignments and = when testing for equality. The operator == does not exist.

Comment: sorry about that. == means "equivalent to". Edited answer for clarity

Comment: OK, so it was not intended to be a Delphi expression. I see!

Comment: Nope. It's been so long since I've used Pascal I forgot about =

Answer (score 2):

It is an extention to standard Pascal, Borland Pascal accepts the pound sign ('#') followed immediately by a decimal number between 0 and 255 as a single character with that code.

Comment: Well, in Delphi 2009+ all strings are Unicode, so you are not restricted to codes between 0 and 255 any more. For example, #$222b is the integral sign. (In Delphi, $ is the hexadecimal prefix.)

Comment: You aren't restricted to that in prior versions, either, @Andreas. Delphi supported Unicode for more than a decade before Delphi 2009.

Comment: Delphi supported WideChar literals for more than a decade?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: But you could not write Caption := #$222b and get an integral sign as the form's caption, right?

Comment: Yes, @Warren. Delphi 4 supported them, and that was released in 1998. Andreas, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned it's a character code, I most often see them used for line breaks in messages, or other control character such as Tab (#9)

```
ShowMessage('Error:'#13#10'Something terrible happened')
```

Strangely it's not necessary to concatinate a string involving these.

Comment: it's better to use the sLineBreak for that functionality though.

Answer (score 0):

It's character code. #97 is equivalent to chr(97) etc etc