# Make AWS Signature Version 4 Request in Delphi 10.3 , porting Python code to Delphi

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, hash

I am trying to build an  AWS Signature Version 4 Request in Delphi.

I manage to handle the signing part but have some issue with the Canonical Request

I am following the link below to create a  Canonical Request 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

If I do it in Python3 see code below
I get the correct answer
f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59

I am trying to do the same in  Delphi

The result is WRONG code
bfc216a33de74e30285fc72d6dd2035508e9aec861e5d56b59f4c1eb4f29ddc3

Anyone now howto do this Python line below in Delphi

```
PYTHON
canonical_request_hash = hashlib.sha256((canonical_request).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

And get this result
f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59

```py
PYTHON CODE
canonical_request = "GET\n"+"/\n"+"Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08\n"+"content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\n"+"host:iam.amazonaws.com\n"+ "x-amz-date:20150830T123600Z\n"+ "\n"+ "content-type;host;x-amz-date\n"+ "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"


canonical_request_hash = hashlib.sha256((canonical_request).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

print(canonical_request_hash)
```

```
DELPHI
 canonical_request :=  'GET\n'+'/\n'+'Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08\n';
 canonical_request := canonical_request +'content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\n'+'host:iam.amazonaws.com\n'+ 'x-amz-date:20150830T123600Z\n"+ "\n"+ "content-type;host;x-amz-date\n'+ 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855';

 canonical_request_hashed :=   BytesToHexConverter ( THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(UTF8Encode( canonical_request )));  // Struggle 

memo1.Lines.Add(canonical_request_hashed);
 memo1.Lines.Add('f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59');

//*********************

function TForm1.BytesToHexConverter(b: Tbytes): string;
var
 I        : Integer;
 s        : String;
begin
 s:='';
 for i  := 0 to length(b)-1 do
   begin
    s:=s+b[i].ToHexString;
   end;
 s:= LowerCase(s);
 result:=s;
End;
```

I expect this result in delphi
f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59
but get this
bfc216a33de74e30285fc72d6dd2035508e9aec861e5d56b59f4c1eb4f29ddc3

Comment: In the Delphi code you have four **double quote** characters that should be **single quote** characters (Delphi string delimiters). They are in: `'x-amz-date:20150830T123600Z\n"+ "\n"+ "content-type;host;x-amz-date\n'+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your'e trying to calculate SHA256 hash from the sample cannonical request that appears on AWS documentation page. As plain text it reads:

> GET
>   /
>   Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08
>   content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
>   host:iam.amazonaws.com
>   x-amz-date:20150830T123600Z
>
> content-type;host;x-amz-date
>   e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

You've successfully converted this plain text to Python string, but you failed to do that in Delphi because of two reasons:

1. You copy-pasted Python code to Delphi and replaced some `"` with `'`, but not all of them as the comment below the question points out.
2. Delphi doesn't allow backslash escapes within string literals. You can only escape single quote `'` by typing two single quotes `''`. All other characters you either type directly or use [# -prefixed character literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975048/what-is-the-symbol-in-pascal). So you should also convert all occurences of `\n` to `#10` (new line character) and put it outside of string literal.

The correct translation to Delphi is:

```
canonical_request :=
  'GET'#10 +
  '/'#10 +
  'Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08'#10 +
  'content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'#10 +
  'host:iam.amazonaws.com'#10 +
  'x-amz-date:20150830T123600Z'#10 + 
  #10 +
  'content-type;host;x-amz-date'#10 +
  'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855';
```

In the end it turns out that it's not a `hexdigest()` issue as written in the title, but rather an issue of porting Python code to Delphi.